# Is there any Ruby or Python interpreter for Lego Mindstorm?

Tags: python, ruby, interpreter, robotics, lego-mindstorms

I want to start coding in Python or Ruby. Since I own a [Lego Midstorms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Robotics) kit I thought it would be nice to program against it. Are there any good translators / interpeters for the Mindstorms brick?

Comment: I wonder if LeJos nxj (java and relatively active) could be used with jruby http://lejos.sourceforge.net/forum/index.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The nxt-python and ruby-nxt projects are remote control interfaces to the NXT. They both run on a PC and remotely control the NXT via Bluetooth or USB.
If you are looking for running alternative firmware on the NXT, there are several different alternatives.

Steve Hassenplug has a webpage with a comprehensive list of all of the known alternative firmware and remote control options.
[NXT Software](http://www.teamhassenplug.org/NXT/NXTSoftware.html)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the pointer to the site, I guess there's a good starting point ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I know it wasn't exactly the answer you were looking for, but like you said, it is a place to start. Maybe someone will create an interpreter for python or ruby in the future. There are already projects for Java and Lua, so python and/or ruby might not be far behind. :)

Answer (score 3):

With python you can use [jaraco.nxt](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/jaraco.nxt) or [nxt-python](http://code.google.com/p/nxt-python/) to control the NXT robot. I don't own one so I've never used any of those.

Found this example using nxt-python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import nxt.locator
from nxt.motor import Motor, PORT_B, PORT_C

def spin_around(b):
        m_left = Motor(b, PORT_B)
        m_left.update(100, 360)
        m_right = Motor(b, PORT_C)
        m_right.update(-100, 360)

sock = nxt.locator.find_one_brick()
if sock:
        spin_around(sock.connect())
        sock.close()
else:
        print 'No NXT bricks found'
```

Seems nice.

Comment: nojevive, if you test this, I'd appreciate some feedback on this python module.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an [open source project for Ruby](http://rubyforge.org/projects/lego-mindstorms/)

Answer (score 1):

Try pynxc 
http://code.google.com/p/pynxc/